# Importing libraries from build.xml file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, java-native-interface, java.library.path

I am developing a java app and I need to use jnativehook library. I have downloaded the .zip from https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/downloads/list . There is a bin folder,src folder,build.xml,build.num and 3 .txt files when I extracted this folder.

I have included this library in my project by File ->  project -> Java project from existing Ant file

And I have tried an example https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/wiki/examples

But I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at GlobalKeyListenerExample.main(GlobalKeyListenerExample.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate the native library.
    at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.loadNativeLibrary(GlobalScreen.java:462)
    at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.<init>(GlobalScreen.java:71)
    at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.<clinit>(GlobalScreen.java:53)
    ... 1 more
```

What location should I give in native library path?

Comment: For 1.1, the jar is included in the binary archive.  In 1.2, there is only a single archive.  If  the library cannot find the correct native library, check that you have write access to the java.io.tmpdir location and that your Operating system and architecture are supported!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through [the source of `GlobalScreen.loadNativeLibrary()`](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/master/src/java/org/jnativehook/GlobalScreen.java#L480), it seems that you get this exception when the library has failed to find the DLL on the `java.library.path` and instead tries to unpack it from the JAR, only to fail to find it.

Some options for fixing this include:

- Checking you are running a supported platform.
- Extract the right DLL from the JAR and place it on the `java.library.path`.

---

To use this library, you only need to include the JAR in your project. I don't like the sound of this part of your question:

> I have included this library in my project by File -> project -> Java project from existing Ant file

Just download [JNativeHook-1.1.4.zip](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/downloads/detail?name=JNativeHook-1.1.4.zip&can=2&q=), extract the ZIP and add the `JNativeHook.jar` JAR to your project.

Comment: But there is no .jar file when i extracted.There is only build.xml file.

Comment: @user3873909 It sounds like you downloaded the src zip. Download exactly the file I've linked to in my answer and you'll find a JAR file in a "jar" folder.